# How do I operate on file using fstream pointers?

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to operate on streams using some abstraction and thus I want to use fstream* instead of ifstream and ofstream. I tried to do sth like that but is wil cause access violation:

```
char* text= "test"; 
fstream* o = new fstream(); 
o = &fstream("name.txt"); 
o->write(text, 4); 
o->close();
```

How can I fix it, or use another idea ?

I want to use pointer in this case (You can look here for more general information) [How to implement my own IO file API in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681574/how-to-implement-my-own-io-file-api-in-c)

After the changes it now looks like this:

```
class GIO_Persistent_File_System : public GIO_CORE
{
public:
GIO_Persistent_File_System(void);
int open(char*, int);
int close();
void write(char* s, int size);
void read(char* s, int size);
public:
~GIO_Persistent_File_System(void);

private:
fstream file;
};

int GIO_Persistent_File_System::open(char* path, int mode){
file.open(path);
return 0;
}

int GIO_Persistent_File_System::close(){
file.close();
return 0;
}

void GIO_Persistent_File_System::write(char* s, int size){
file.write(s, size);
return;
}

void GIO_Persistent_File_System::read(char* s, int size){
file.read(s, size);
return;
}
```

MAIN:

```
GIO_CORE* plik = new GIO_Persistent_File_System();
char* test = new char[10];
char* napis = "testgs";
plik->open("name.txt", OPEN_MODE);
plik->write(napis, 2);
//plik->read(test,2);
plik->close();
```

And this code seems like working altough **I cannot find the file**. I checked and the current directory is pointed correctly (ProjectName/Debug)

I checked it and **changing fstream to ofstream will works** as it should and I can find the file. But since I want to achieve some level of abstraction and **I would like to use fstream**. How can I fix it ?

Comment: This code will give you an error, not cause an access violation.

Comment: I see three compiler errors.

Comment: Why are we using a pointer here? you are not gaining anything by doing so.

Comment: The code is compiling without errors.

Comment: Adre: in this simple example there is no point in using pointers. But in the general I would like to use pointers

Comment: What are your command line options?

Comment: I assume the OP is using Visual Studio, which allows taking addresses of temporaries as an extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will give you an error, since you can't take the address of a temporary object, as you are doing with `&fstream("name.txt")`.

```
error: taking address of temporary
```

Also, note that the conversion from a string literal to a `char*` has been deprecated and is invalid in C++11. Use a `const char*` instead:

```
const char* text = "test";
```

Nonetheless, let's look at what you're *trying* to do. Firstly, you are dynamically allocating an `fstream` and initialising a pointer to that object:

```
fstream* o = new fstream();
```

Then in the next line, you create a temporary object with `fstream("name.txt")` and then take its address and assign it to `o` (which gives an error, as we've seen). Now you would have lost any access to the dynamically allocated `fstream` and instead have `o` pointing at a now destroyed temporary object.

Dereferencing that pointer (with `o->`) will give you undefined behaviour.

You are overcomplicating this. You do not need to dynamically allocate your `fstream` object or use pointers at all. Instead, try:

```
fstream o("name.txt");
o.write(text, 4);
o.close();
```

---

With your updated code, the problem is that you are writing 0 bytes:

```
plik->write(napis, 0);
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
plik->write(napis, 6);
```

Comment: If I use fstream o as You said and initialize it in header file of my class. And then in Open(char* path) in my class try to do o = fstream(path) it will cause compilation errors. That's why I wanted to use pointer

Comment: @SebastianCygert You should just be doing `o.open(path)`.

Comment: It seems like working (no errors) but actually no file is created in the directory. As it was created with your solution                        fstream o("name.txt");
o.write(text, 4);
o.close();

Comment: @SebastianCygert Edit your new code into the question exactly as is. Do not modify it.

Comment: @SebastianCygert The problem is that you're passing a size of 0: `plik->write(napis, 0);`

Comment: @sftrabbit - look at the new edit just at the end of the question

Comment: @SebastianCygert I believe you might be seeing a Visual Studio bug. Try `file.open(path, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);`

Comment: Oops, sorry I just reordered our comments there. There's a VS bug where the `std::fstream::in` forces it to be an input file only, even if you specify `std::fstream::out`. `std::fstream::trunc` for some reason forces it back again.

Comment: Ok, this is really amazing. Made my day

Comment: For opening I can just put file.open(path). But for writing I have to use your fix. Is there a way to open a file for both operations ?

Comment: Even though the answer is technically correct for the given example, it doesn't answer the question how to instantiate a stream object using new.

Answer (score 2):

There's hardly ever need to have a *pointer* to `fstream`. Just do this:

```
std::ofstream o("name.txt");
o.write(napis, 4);
o.close();
```

Notice that `o` will also close when it goes out of scope, so often you don't even have to call `close()`.