# how to open fstream for both reading and writing operation in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, fstream

For my project I want to use Fstream to open file and I want to open it for both reading and writing operations at once. I am using Visual Studio.
Normally it would be just `file.open();` but since there is a bug in Visual Studio (You can find more on it in this topic [How do I operate on file using fstream pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684052/how-do-i-operate-on-file-using-fstream-pointers) in comments to sftrabbit answer) it is not that easy. 
`File.Open()` will open the file only for reading (writing will make no effect) and to open in that way file for writing we need to do `file.open(path, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc)` but this will open it only for writing, not for reading.

Any ideas how to open the file with just one line ?

Comment: "but this will open it only for writing, not for reading" - what makes you think so?

Comment: the standard specifies `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>* open(const char* s,
ios_base::openmode mode);` so opening with just open() is not guaranteed to give read/write. Some compilers might have a default value for the mode but it is not a bug if they don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple code.

```
stream file;
file.open(fileName,ios::in | ios::out);
```

The symbol to be used between flags is the `piping` symbol.

Comment: Let's call the symbol the `bitwise OR`. Piping is an operation you can do in the Linux OS that is quite different from what this code is doing.